# psiTurk: AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'get_connections'

Tags: python-2.7, openshift

Before I begin, let me give the disclaimer that I'm very new at this sort of thing, that my explanation may not be too coherent, and I have no ability to separate what might and might not be important.

I'd like to run psiTurk. But because psiturk doesn't work on Windows, I'm using Openshift to run Python, with psiturk inside of that. I've gotten Openshift working using PuTTY, and have gotten as far as launching the psiTurk shell. But even when I enter the command to turn the server on, the server remains off with the following error message.

```
[psiTurk server:off mode:sdbx #HITs:0]$ server on
Experiment server launching...
Now serving on myurl.rhcloud.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/openshift/[my SSH]/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmd2.py", line 789, in onecmd_plus_hooks
stop = self.postcmd(stop, statement)
File "/var/lib/openshift/[my SSH]/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psiturk/psiturk_shell.py", line 205, in postcmd
self.color_prompt()
File "/var/lib/openshift/[my SSH]/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psiturk/psiturk_shell.py", line 571, in color_prompt
server_status = self.server.is_server_running()
File "/var/lib/openshift/[my SSH]/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psiturk/experiment_server_controller.py", line 144, in is_server_running
psiturk_exp_ports = [process[0].laddr[1] for process in [psutil.Process(int(pid)).get_connections() for pid in output]]
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'get_connections'
'Process' object has no attribute 'get_connections'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you following the instructions on page 7 of this pdf? https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/psiturk/latest/psiturk.pdf

Comment: I've been using these: http://psiturk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html. UPDATE: they appear to be the same thing.

Comment: Are you using this section (http://psiturk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/openshift.html) of the docs?

Comment: Yes, I've been using a variety of areas in the documentation to help me, that one included.

Comment: Update: After changing some of the config files, it simply says '[psiTurk server:off mode:sdbx #HITs:0]' and refuses to turn the server on with the command, giving no error message at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like standard `pip install psiturk` installs a version of the `psutil` library that's not compatible with `psiturk`. What worked for me was installing directly from git:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/NYUCCL/psiTurk.git@master
```

See this PR for details: https://github.com/NYUCCL/psiTurk/pull/192

Also, it's best to make a virtualenv to avoid problems with already-installed packages.